# executing commands inside makefile

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

I'm executing the following command inside my makefile. It's giving me an error when I have to open file2. In other words, if there are any changes in file1.c based on the switches I select, the make fails exactly at this line.

```
unifdef -DSW1 -DSW2 -USW3 file1.c >file2.c
```

Okay, unifdef is an utility that does partial preprocessing for me. file1.c is input to unifdef and file2.c is output. My makefile is plain and simple and I don't have any dependencies to either file1.c or file2.c. Makefile dependencies are working out okay.

Thanks,

Comment: What errors are you getting? And why do you think this is related to `make` but don't show any parts of your `Makefile`?

Comment: Is this an action related to a dependency between `file1` and `file2`? Something else?

Comment: Looking at your previous questions I see that they have also been rather imprecise and lightly specified. Perhaps reading the [wow to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) document would give you some guidance for future questions. The thing that you need to keep in mind is that while you;ve been working on the problem and know what you want to do *we don't have any of that context*, so you have to tell us.

Answer (score 0):

By default unifdef exits with status code 1 if it makes any changes to the input file. Make treats this as a failure. You can tell make to ignore the exit status by prefixing the command with a -

Version 2.7 of unifdef (which was released in March 2013) has a -x option to control the exit status logic, so it plays more nicely with make. You might want to use -x1 so that make will ensure that unifdef did actually make changes. See http://dotat.at/prog/unifdef/